# how to set default datetime for 10 minutes after in laravel migration?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, datetime

I want to set default datetime now + 10 minutes after now, for a column in migration like following :

`$table->dateTime('expire_at')->useCurrent() + 10 minutes;`

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative you can try to set value in `boot` method in your model:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::creating(function ($query) {
        $query->expire_at = Carbon::now()->addMinutes(10);
    });
}
```

Comment: I'd go this way aswell, you'll have more control, what if 6 months it's 20 minutes? It'll be easier to edit from here